# Numpy log2 returning NaN for small values

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I've the following data frame with all positive values

```
    V1          V2          V3      V4          V5
0  F1H5N4S2  10.751263  0.216574  0.703209  10.674107
1    F2H4N7  12.131079  0.000004  1.883824   0.018118
2     H12N2  11.075072  0.214872  0.000004  10.674107
3      H3N7   1.091061  0.000004  3.503290   0.091797
4    F2H4N5   0.590545  0.000004  1.730215   0.223571
```

When I'm trying to convert the numerical values to log2 using the following syntax in numpy(np)

```
log2df = df.apply(lambda x: np.log2(x) if np.issubdtype(x.dtype, np.float) else x)
```

I'm getting the following data frame with NaNs in place of log2(0.000004). 0.000004 happens to be the smallest value in the dataframe which I imputed.
Can anyone help me solve the problem?
Thanks

```
    V1          V2          V3      V4          V5
0  F1H5N4S2  3.426434 -2.207070 -0.507974  3.416043
1    F2H4N7  3.600636       NaN  0.913664 -5.786433
2     H12N2  3.469244 -2.218451       NaN  3.416043
3      H3N7  0.125732       NaN  1.808710 -3.445414
4    F2H4N5 -0.759880       NaN  0.790951 -2.161198
```

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. What happens if you do e.g., `np.log2(df['V3'])`? And what if you do `np.log2(df.loc[3,'V3'])`?

Comment: Also: what are your Python, NumPy and Pandas version?

Comment: Could you add the piece of code to your question to create the problematic dataframe? And then check for yourself that if you create that dataframe and immediately after it, you run your apply, you get the same problem? That is, no other operations are used to either create or manipulate the dataframe before or in between.

Comment: pandas: 0.25.1
numpy: 1.16.5
Looks like these are outdated, let me update these

Comment: Indeed, Pandas has reached its 1.x series.

Comment: np.log2(df['V3'])? And what if you do np.log2(df.loc[3,'V3']) no Na N, both are giving expected results

Comment: It will be easier for someone to help you if you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works fine for me, but avoid using apply. Select the numeric type and apply a vectorial operation:

```
cols = df.select_dtypes('number').columns

df[cols] = np.log2(df[cols])
```

output:

```
         V1        V2         V3         V4        V5
0  F1H5N4S2  3.426434  -2.207068  -0.507975  3.416043
1    F2H4N7  3.600636 -17.931569   0.913664 -5.786432
2     H12N2  3.469244  -2.218451 -17.931569  3.416043
3      H3N7  0.125732 -17.931569   1.808710 -3.445409
4    F2H4N5 -0.759881 -17.931569   0.790951 -2.161195
```